# C# - BindingSource remove current

Tags: c#, winforms

I have c# windows form app that it has a DataGridView that connected to a view of sql server and some TextBoxes that connected to a table of sql server.
Now I want to remove an item from my DataGridView but when I use

```
tbl_BindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
```

it removes the last item that I added to my database not selected one.
How can I remove selected item from my DataGridView?
Please help!

```
tbl_BindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
tbl_TableAdapter.Update(ds.tbl);
view_showTableAdapter.Fill(ds.view_show);
view_showDataGridView.Refresh();
```

EDIT:

I counld'nt find a way to use BindingSource for delete.
so I used this:

```
    DSet.tbl_Row row = ds.tbl.FindById 
    (view_showDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    int indexRow = ds.tbl.Rows.IndexOf(row);
    ds.tbl.Rows[indexRow].Delete();

    tbl_TableAdapter.Update(ds.tbl);
    view_showTableAdapter.Fill(ds.view_show);
    view_showDataGridView.Refresh();
```

Comment: If you look at the `Current` property before calling `RemoveCurrent()`, what does that show?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I used                     MessageBox.Show(tbl_cdBindingSource.Current.ToString()); and it showed
 System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: I was suggesting using the debugger to look - so you can see what's *in* that `DataRowView`. (Or you could log a specific value from it, potentially.) The point is to see whether `Current` refers to the selected value you expect to be removed or not.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new in C#. Now I set a break point for the line has current and I saw the selected row was the last one that I added to database and not the selected one

Comment: Right, so it looks like that's the thing to focus on for the moment - I don't know much about data binding myself, but you should research how to make the "current" row the "selected" one. There may be a property you need to set somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help.